Swift: What is the rationale behind forbidding named parameters for closures?
In Swift, functions can be defined with named parameters, for example:
func greet(person: String) -> String {
    ...
}

which need to be used when the function is called :
greet(person: "Anna")

But it's not allowed to pass named parameters to closures.
What is the reason for such difference between named functions and closures in the language design?

Questions like this one tend to get closed as being opinion-based. Can you [edit] your question to include the research you've done? Can you describe a situation where named parameters in a closure would have solved a problem?

In Swift, named parameters are not part of a function type, but are part of the function name. The functions foo(_:_:) and bar(_:param:) both take 2 params and might have the same type. Closures do not have a name, they are anonymous functions. You cannot declare a variable with labels (e.g. let myClosure(x:y:) = {...}. Parameter labels get erased when using a function or closure as a value. This changed in Swift 3, see https://github.com/swiftlang/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0111-remove-arg-label-type-significance.md

@amon This is exactly the kind of non-opinion based answer a curious reader would expect. I vote to reopen the question so that you can post it.

Thank you @Christophe for editing.

@GregBurghardt I don't understand why this is opinion based. The designers of Swift had a reason to design their language like that. I'm interested in that reason.

@DarkTrick see Is asking "why" on language specifications still considered as "primarily opinion-based" if it can have official answers?

@DarkTrick: "why the designers designed their language as it looks like" is 100% opinion based - that is not a helpful wording. Whether passing named parameters to closures would collide with other design decisions made for Swift, however, is an answerable question.  Gnat is a hardliner who seems always to pick the interpretation which justifies closing a question, don't expect to convince him easily that his interpretation was too single-edged.  But maybe others have a different POV on this, just wait a day or so.

FYI I don't intend to turn my comment into a full answer, but I invite everyone else to use the material as a basis for their writeup. I suspect that looking for the discussions surrounding that Swift Enhancement Proposal would provide futher explanation and rationale.

In this case there is a rational and good answer. Unfortunately you don’t know that when you ask the question. You need an answer to know if it was a good question or not.

@gnat I removed the "why" interpretation of the question in the title.

This was decided in SE-0111, Remove type system significance of function argument labels, which cites the following motivation:

Motivation
...
As currently implemented, this feature can lead to surprising behavior:
func sinkBattleship(atX x: Int, y: Int) -> Bool { /* ... */ }

func meetsBattingAverage(ofHits hits: Int, forRuns runs: Int) -> Bool { /* ... */ }

var battingAveragePredicate : (ofHits: Int, forRuns: Int) -> Bool = meetsBattingAverage
battingAveragePredicate = sinkBattleship

// sinkBattleship is invoked
battingAveragePredicate(ofHits: 1, forRuns: 2)

Removing this feature simplifies the type system.

In other words, the argument labels were in a strange limbo, where they were significant enough to impact the inferred type of variables (e.g. battingAveragePredicate infers as (ofHits: Int, forRuns: Int) -> Bool), but were also loose enough that sinkBattleship could be assigned, despite having different argument labels.
The result is a call where the labels are (ofHits: 1, forRuns: 2), but actually behave as a call to (atX: 1, y: 2). This was confusing, and just got torn out entirely.

@Craig Fixed, thanks! I've run into that min limit before, I find it quite annoying haha

Your fix is better, I was going to put it in the wrong place. :)
